# Mysql - variable equal or lower from string

Tags: php, mysql

how can I list rows in mysql where one of data is equal or lower from given, data is string.

**DB**

> element 1 -> '50cm', '30cm', '20cm', '10cm'
>
> element 2 -> '49cm', '58cm', '43cm', '100cm'
>
> element 3 -> '60cm', '88cm', '33cm', '60cm'
>
> **Query -> find el = '50cm'**

**Result**

> element 1 -> '50cm', '30cm', '20cm', '10cm'
>
> element 2 -> '49cm', '58cm', '43cm', '100cm'

Thanks

Comment: What are "elements"? Are they rows? Is "each" cm value in its own column? Why do you have numbers and units in the same value? Huh?

Comment: Normally these kind of data is stored in two columns `value & unit` and all comparisons done on the `value` column. is this something that you can consider changing?

Comment: If they are all appended with 'cm', you don't need to specify 'cm' and you could just use int anyway.

Comment: So, in one table i stored element_types (eq. heater, fridge, couch).
In second id_element_types and name of 4 fields (eq. for heater [width, height, weight, power], couch [width, depth, color, style])
In first scenario client want only show the data on front so i stored all data as string, but now he want to add search engine and find all products that are equal or lower to search element. Sometimes it will be cm, sometines inch ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try, but I am not sure if will do the job:

```
SELECT  CAST(column_name AS UNSIGNED) as m FROM MY_TABLE where m < CAST('50cm' AS UNSIGNED) ;
```

Basically you transform the 50cm to a integer, 50 and then you compare them.

In theory as the people mentioned you should have had 2 columns, one for values and one for unit.